# Problems with Snapshot / Volume shadow copy and MySQL Freeze on Windows server 2003

Tags: mysql, vmware, windows-server-2003

I've setup a PHP-application (1 server) and 1 mysql-database-master-server (Windows server 2003). Every day I get a automatic warning from the application that the database-server was not reachable for 1 or several minutes.

In the Event-logging I see that The 'Volume Shadow Copy service' or 'Snapshot Provider' from the 'Service control manager' does something (event 7035 and 7036).

I already had problems with the Sync-driver and disabled/uninstalled it.
I already make backups with mysqldump to a storage-environment.

How do I disable the VSS of vmWare snapshot provider?

Answer (score 0):

Unchecking the `VSS components` while installing VMware Tools on the guest OS should prevent it from using VSS during snapshot creation.

Source: http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1007696